# Where to get polygons for german postcodes (from OSM, in GeoJSON)?

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, geojson

I want to draw a choropleth map based on german zipcode areas and some data.
It should look like this, just down to zipcodes:
https://maps.aimpulse.com/osm/addresses/

I asked the osm irc channel and have been told that it might even be possible with leaflet.js

So I read a bit here and there but I couldn't even find any starting point.

So any ideas are welcome.

---

Edit: Thanks to the answer and comment so far I think my main question is:

How do I get a list of german zipcode/postcode areas, with the corresponding coordinates for the polygons?

According to the irc channel, OpenStreetMap (OSM) has this data, and it should be possible to have it in GeoJSON format.

Comment: You should start by (a) grabbing a hold of some german postcode polygons and (b) reading the [Leaflet choropleth tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/)

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial. I guess (a) is the main thing I need help about. I'll edit the question appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you could/should use leaflet.js.

You simply can create a map and add osm as TileLayer. After adding OSM tilelayer you can add your zipcode information. 
The question is: how do you get them?

If you have the data as file (geojson) you can add a geojson layer.
leaflet.js has many other options to add the zipcode information.

I am quite sure that leaflet.js can do the trick.

So you can start with:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([50.106545, 8.638599], 15);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

Now it depends on your zipcode-data how to implement them in leaflet.

Comment: Ah maybe there is an misunderstanding. Drawing a map with leaflet is easy. But I only have the zipcode + according data.
The guys in the irc channel told me osm has the zipcode area data. But how do I connect my zipcodes (strings) with that.
I found leaflet can draw polygons but it seems not to have a direct connection to osm areas to draw them?

Answer (score 1):

Now I get it!
Getting those information is quite difficult!

You can try getting the zipcodes from the "Geoportal" - probably using the search word "Verwaltungsgrenzen".
Otherwise you can have a look at the OSM Boundaries. But those informations are incomplete.

The german "post office" also hold those data, but this might be expensive!

Comment: I looked at http://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/ and it seems there are a lot of infos. The problem is to get them into the needed polygon data as all info I can find is always incomplete or just bad.
I tried with osmfilter and osmconvert a bit but it seems I need another application to extract the boundary data as polygon information.

Comment: But it must be possible somehow, I found this page: https://osm.wno-edv-service.de/pcboundaries/
It allows to extract this data, as GeoJson even!
But you have to click all the areas and besides that would take a lot of time alone, I wouldn't want to stress that guys server. Plus I want to figure out how to do it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this [repository](https://github.com/yetzt/postleitzahlen/blob/master/data/postleitzahlen.geojson) with that information, I don't know if it is updated but works.